# How can I upload my dataset with option to choose either xls,xlsx and csv for my Shiny Dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, rshiny

Im currently doing an application using Shiny Dashboard for dataset analytics application. But after using the tutorial by shiny dashboard, i found out that i couldnt upload xls, and xlsx type of files.

Sorry, first time using Shiny Dashboard.

Comment: What is the function you used to read the files in your R shiny code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the file extension and use the appropriate file reader according to this extension.

In `ui`:

```
fileInput("file", "Upload a file")
```

In `server`:

```
dataset <- eventReactive(input$file, {
  extension <- tools::file_ext(input$file$name)
  filepath <- input$file$datapath
  switch(extension,
    csv = read.csv(filepath),
    xls = readxl::read_xls(filepath),
    xlsx = readxl::read_xlsx(filepath)
  )
})
```

Comment: It is working, however i have extra question since it is working. How can we convert it to dataframe and remove the header since it is xls and xlsx format (based on your given codes since i understand it easily through your codes)?

Comment: @MackyKavinsky I don't understand your questions. This returns a dataframe, so what do you mean by converting to a dataframe? And what do you mean by removing the header? A dataframe has column names, corresponding to the header. Do you want to change the column names?

Comment: oh, what i meant was every xls, and xlsx file has their own header. How do i exclude them or did the header automatically skipped?